# Question on proper use of Grid or Table. HTML/CSS best practice question

Tags: html, css

I'm running into some issues while trying to make a "service-schedule," basically I only want the page to have a table(but I want to to all be in a "grid") Because I've found that it's easier to have a "grid" table then to actually use a real table.

However, essentially my "Grid-container" is my grid and I'm wondering if it is a bad practice to do that? How can I fix it. So on. I know that my code most likely has other errors like having 7 unique ids for what could be a class.

1 of the issues i'm having is labeling the top part of the "table"(which is actually the grid-container(truly) as a month and "table-header" which it is.

I've tried doing a grid-element Table inside a grid element table. When using a grid should everything be turned into a grid element?

https://jsfiddle.net/9dm51zgr/1/

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <table class="main-table">
            <div class="month"> July </div>

            <table class="installer">
                <tr>
                    <th>Installers </th>
                </tr>
                <!-- Installer header -->
                <tr id="installer-row-1">
                    <td id="installer-name-1"> Installer </td=>
                </tr>
                <!-- Inst #1 -->
                <tr id="installer-row-2">
                    <td id="installer-name-2"> Installer </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Inst #2 -->
                <tr id="installer-row-3">
                    <td id="installer-name-3"> Installer </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Inst #3 -->
                <tr id="installer-row-4">
                    <td id="installer-name-4"> Installer </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Inst #4 -->
                <tr id="installer-row-5">
                    <td id="installer-name-5"> Installer </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Inst #5 -->
                <tr id="installer-row-6">
                    <td id="installer-name-6"> Installer </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Inst #6 -->
                <tr id="installer-row-7">
                    <td id="installer-name-7"> Installer </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- Inst #7 -->
            </table>

            <div class="jobs"></div>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid; `</td=></tr>` and you seem to have extra `</div></table>`.

Comment: Try to think about what im asking, not the minor details. I dont think those errors effected anything. I'm more worried about the best way to go about making a table using grid

Comment: David is right but for the div table your closing div for <div class="main"> should be outside your table

Comment: I think people are going to be distracted by the simple errors/details before they get to your question

Comment: Fix the problems that "don't matter" and then we can focus on what your problem is. As written it seems you want to show tabular data from a `<table>` element using CSS Grid to recreate a `<table>` layout. This doesn't really make sense to me, though I may be misunderstanding the question.

Comment: The whole page is going to be a "schedule" page. That I want to have a clickable links linking to other pages. Does that seem foolish to you? or perhaps in the future I may want to resize the entire table element to fit a sidebar, header, so forth. I think what you're saying does make a lot of sense tho and i definetly will not go that route because you are absolutely right in the fact hta I may very well wish to resize it and add mor.

Comment: Am I too stupid for this?

Comment: As mentioned, use `<table>` for tabular data, what you have provided us so far looks more like a list, so more suited to `ol` or `ul`.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, the only "proper" usage of a `<table>` is when displaying tabular data.

This should mean a case where you display a set of elements with similar (or identical) structure so that each of their properties are displayed one below the other, making table specific tasks easier to perform (or follow), such as: calculating a column's total or reordering the rows based on values of a particular property of each element.

In practice, what the `<table>` element does (and why it should be avoided, in most cases) is: it tracks the contents (hence size) of each of the cells making sure all of them are aligned on both directions.

From the rendering process's point of view, this is extremely expensive. So expensive that even large companies, like Microsoft and Google, when they developed online versions of their spreadsheet products (Excel and Google Sheets), they didn't use `<table>` elements to display, well... tables. They used `<div>` elements positioned absolutely while enabling all the functionality you'd expect from a table via JavaScript.
To anyone who might think that's irrelevant, take into account both of these companies have intimate knowledge of the rendering process and its optimizations. Yet, both came to the conclusion it is more efficient to process and render cells as `<div>`s than it is to do the same using `<table>` elements.

**Note:** When I say `<div>`s and `<table>`s I don't necessarily refer to those tags *per-se* (as a `<div>` can have `display:table` and a `<table>` can have `display:block`). I mean the block/flex/grid model display mechanisms vs the table model display mechanism.

That should give you an idea about how expensive rendering a `<table>` really is and why everyone insists that it should never be used for layout.

---

To summarize: I'm not actually saying you shouldn't use `<table>`s. But I'm saying you shouldn't use them if the overall page performance matters, which is:

- if you have to render a significant number of tables (more than 10)
- if you plan on performing any DOM manipulation on each cell, resulting in the cell being resized. This degrades really fast, as each cell triggers a size recalculation of the entire table. The downgrade in performance is noticeable from 100 cells up.

---

In your particular case, rendering a calendar, the proper solution would be to use either `display:grid` or `display:flex`. 
But, again, if you only want to render one month and it takes you less to do so using a `<table>`, use one.

In the end, best practice in web development should be pursued when it doesn't stand in the way of completing the task in a timely manner and when not using it won't make other future (and required) tasks involving the code impossible or extremely costly.

---

From your question it is not currently clear if you're rendering months, weeks or days in a year, days or weeks in a month or days in a week.
If you need more help with your particular case, please update the question with details on what the challenge is, what you have tried in order to solve it and links to any documentation stating the method you tried should have worked.

To demonstrate the lack of need for `display:table` in a calendar, here's a quick prototype (~ 1hr). Purposefully, I didn't use a model/example, so I didn't get biased by their markup.
I did use Vue (notorious as a fast prototyping tool) and moment.js, a must-have when dealing with time in JavaScript, IMHO:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#calendar',
  data: () => ({
    months: moment.months(),
    year: moment().year(),
    fontSize: 14,
  }),
  methods: {
    daysInMonth(month, year) {
      year = year || this.year;
      return moment([year, month, 1]).daysInMonth();
    },
    getWeekday(day, month, year) {
      year = year || this.year;
      month = month || moment().month();
      return moment([year, month, day]).day();
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.month-days {
  width: 13em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.month-days:after {
  content: '';
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.month-days > span {
  flex: 0 0 calc(13em / 7);
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: .3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.today {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.calendar {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  max-width: 60em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.title {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding: .2em 0;
}
.month {
  padding: .75em;
}
.year {
  max-width: 60em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}
.year input {
  width: 6em;
  margin: 1rem;
}
.year input[type="number"] {
  margin: 0;
  width: 3.3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>

<div id="calendar">
  <template>
    <div>
      <div class="year">
        font-size ({{fontSize}}px): <input type="range" v-model="fontSize" max="24" min="8">
        year (<input type="number" v-model="year" max="1e4" min="-1e4">): <input type="range" v-model="year" max="1e4" min="-1e4">
      </div>
      <div class="calendar" :style="{ fontSize: `${fontSize}px` }">
        <div v-for="(month, m) in months" :key="m" class="month">
          <div class="title" v-text="month"></div>
          <div class="month-days">
            <span v-for="e in getWeekday(1, m, year)" :key="`empty-${e}`"></span>
            <span v-for="d in daysInMonth(m, year)" :key="`day-${d}`" v-text="d"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: This would be a weekly schedule. However that being said I would like to be "optimized," as I'm also going to make a 31 day schedule ( and who knows how many more schedules will come after that. That being said should i make a <div> with display: table or is that the same as making a table?

Comment: Using table display properties on any elements attempts to enforce the same rendering rules on them as for table elements. In fact, if you do use a table, i'd recommend using table elements (`<tr>`, `<td>`, `<th>`. etc...). That said, could you provide more details on what it is you are trying to achieve (screenshot!?), on how is it supposed to handle large differences in cell contents, how is it going to display on devices of different widths? Without the above nobody can have an informed opinion on what would be appropriate. So far you're nowhere near the requirements for a `<table>`.

Comment: When reviewing usage of a `<table>` element, there are cases where display of tabular data should not be done using a `<table>` and there are cases where non-tabular data could easily be rendered using a `<table>` (reducing dev time without significant side-effects). But the decision comes from understanding the mechanics of a `<table>` element (sketched above), knowing all of the alternatives, and from a proper understanding of the requirements in that particular case. In your case, they are not available. I answered your general question but without more detail I can't help further.

Comment: It's like this. We have installers who go out to the job to do some service.

I want there names down the left side. Then I want on top Mon Tue Wed Thursday Friday. In the box will be the particular job.

Answer (score 0):

At present you are nesting one `<table>` inside another `<table>`.

I'd suggest that's a sub-optimal approach and certainly not best presentational practice.

In order of preference, I'd try the following:

1. CSS Grid
2. CSS Tables
3. CSS Flexbox (using `flex-wrap: wrap`)
4. HTML `<table>` (using `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes to avoid nesting)

Comment: This seems correct. I have read some stuff online but nothin that at filled in the whole picture for me. And truthfully this question is designed(i think) to show my lack of skills and maybe get people to tell me some resources that would help me. I know liek ws3 or w3c whatever it is and I use that as a reference but do you have anyone more indepth sources/learning material/web pages that could help me with this type of thing?

Comment: I would recommend familiarising yourself with (and learning and using) lots and lots of HTML Elements (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) and lots and lots of CSS Properties (https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/all-properties.en.html). You'll find Pareto's rule applies - 20% of each of the two vocabularies is what you'll use 80% of the time. Once you are familiar with large parts of these two vocabularies, you can learn Javascript (ES2015+) and JSON and SVG.